# DNN module not working it is stuck in load sequence

Tags: dotnetnuke-7

I have a DNN module, which is stuck in load sequence. When the page load everything is working fine except this module.

[image]

Even when I enter edit mode, the module is still in the loading phase.
I checked on dev site as well, and this module seems to be working fine there.

The version is the same on both dev and live site for the module and the DNN version is the same as well, no changes have been made.

I am also getting these console errors related to the module

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Clearly the module has some javascript errors which is cascading through the page.  What is the name and version of the module?

Comment: this is the Digital Asset Module, version 7.3.3. The DNN version is also 07.03.03. One thing I dont understand is that, the same version and settings is on the dev site and the module is working fine there and not on live site. It was working fine before but something happened